# When setting WindowStartuPlocation to Manual, it is not set or top and top.(in wpf prism library)

Tags: wpf, prism

Set the popup dialog style as shown below.

```
<prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="Manual" />
        <Setter Property="Left" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Top" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowActivated" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>

<Grid>
    <Button/>
</Grid>
```

However, if you show dialog, it pops up to the ownercenter position.
How should I solve this problem?

I forcibly entered the Left and Top attributes in the onDialogopened Event, but it didn't work because it was still a popup.
When the other button is pressed, I confirmed that it operates when sets of Left and Top, but what I want is a popup in a position set to Manual as soon as it is popup.